# Can I count on partition preserving order?

Tags: ruby, implementation-agnostic

Say I have a sorted Array, such as this:

```
myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Suppose I call [`Enumerable#partition`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition) on it:

```
p myArray.partition(&:odd?)
```

Must the output always be the following?

```
[[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]
```

The documentation doesn't state this; this is what it says:

> ## partition { |obj| block } → [ true_array, false_array ]
> partition → [an_enumerator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerator.html)
>
> Returns two arrays, the first containing the elements of enum for which the block evaluates to true, the second containing the rest.
>
> If no block is given, an enumerator is returned instead.

But it seems logical to assume `partition` works this way.

Through testing Matz's interpreter, it appears to be the case that the output works like this, and it makes full sense for it to be like this. However, can I count on `partition` working this way regardless of the Ruby version or interpreter?

<sub>Note: I made [implementation-agnostic](/questions/tagged/implementation-agnostic) because I couldn't find any other tag that describes my concern. Feel free to change the tag to something better if you know about it.</sub>

Comment: Well, to be sure, you just have to download the other two big alternative rubies and see for yourself. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev How do I find what rubyspec has to say? I tried running `ri Enumerable#partition`, but it says `Nothing known about Enumerable#partition` and also it doesn't list anything when I drop the `#partition`

Comment: You just can be sure about that :)

Comment: @MaximPontyushenko How do you know?

Comment: Check the history of commits about this function and it looks like it hasn't  changed since [at least 2003](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blame/aebf152ea4df405a1519a4bcd41707ad72f9deb7/enum.c) and yeah I see I could bee wrong:)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev That's no enough, you'd have to verify it with all Ruby implementations, including those that haven't been written yet. Specs aren't just about current behavior, they're also about future proofing. This is one reason that the "try it and see" approach is nonsense.

Comment: @muistooshort: well, but given that ruby has no spec, what do you propose?

Comment: If `partition` didn't always behave the way it clearly should wouldn't there be angry mobs in the streets?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Don't assume anything that isn't in the documentation, read the ChangeLogs on every release, and hope things don't get any sloppier. Standards committees slow things down quite a bit but they do serve a valuable purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't rely on the order.  The reason is parallelism.

A traditional serial implementation of `partition` would loop through each element of the array evaluating the block one at a time in order.  As each call to `odd` returns, it's immediately pushed into the appropriate true or false array.

Now imagine an implementation which takes advantage of multiple CPU cores.  It still iterates through the array in order, but *each call to `odd` can return out of order*.  `odd(myArray[2])` might return before `odd(myArray[0])` resulting in `[[3, 1, 5], [2, 4, 6]]`.

List processing idioms such as `partition` which run a list through a function (most of [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html)) benefit greatly from parallel processing, and most computers these days have multiple cores.  I wouldn't be surprised if a future Ruby implementation took advantage of this.  The writers of the API documentation for Enumerable likely carefully omitted any mention of process ordering to leave this optimization possibility open.

Comment: Interesting, but not definitive.  The coder still has control. If the coder wants the results in a particular order, that will happen, parallelism notwithstanding.

Comment: @CarySwoveland How would they exert this control? `partition`, and most of the Enumerable interface, takes no options.

Comment: Perhaps the suggestion is that the Enumerable interface would gain a method similar to `lazy` which instead was called something like `parallel`.

Comment: I'd be veeeery surprised (in a bad way) if `map` changed the order. I hope this never happens.

Comment: All I'm saying is that if I were a Ruby monk charged with writing the code for `partition`, I obviously could ensure that it returned arrays ordered the way I wanted them ordered, regardless of the computer my code were run on.

Comment: Ordering is not mentioned in the docs for most Enumerable methods because it may not be defined.  For example, `[1,2,3].to_set.select { |i| i > 1 }` is only guaranteed to return `[2,3]` or `[3,2]`. (Why [Array#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select)'s docs don't mention order I do not know. I think it should.)

Comment: The `Enumerable` protocol is very narrow. It can rely *only* on `each` and nothing else. I'm going to conjecture that `partition` is stable wrt to `each`, and that any implementation of it that doesn't honor this is going to be considered defective, even if the spec currently doesn't say this clearly. In Ruby, the "spec" is a rather nebulous concept, it's basically "what the YARV testsuite says + what matz says + what the community reasonably expects + what widely used books say + the sourcecode of YARV".

Comment: Very good advice, Jörg. If one were constantly concerned with such "what if"s, it would be hard to get any work done. I look at it like this. If I were charged with maintaining the source for `partition`, would I consider changing the order of elements returned from the order they are fed to me by `each`? If the answer is "Not in a million years!" (in part for fear of being lynched), I don't worry about it.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev You're right, including `map` was a goof.

Comment: This is a good thought, but the more I think about it, the more I think that your answer won't ever work out to be true. For instance, Java has its stream API. To invoke parallelism, it's necessary to explicitly call `.parallel()` or `.parallelStream()`, otherwise it is guaranteed that order will be preserved. I believe that ruby will not ever change this, since the preservation of order is expected when dealing with enumerables. If ruby decides to add parallelism, it will have to do it with something like `ParallelEnumerable`.

Comment: @Justin I agree it is likely that a lot of code does, probably without realizing it, make this assumption. However, languages have made similar decisions in the past. Perl hashes used to be fairly deterministic, but [5.18 changed it so the order was randomized](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.18.2/perl5180delta.html#Hash-overhaul). They knew this would break a lot of code, but the benefits were too good. Having a special `ParallelEnumerable` class would avoid this problem, but it would also mean existing code would not benefit from parallel processing. I wouldn't risk it.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation makes no explicit mention of this, but judging from the [official code](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/437392232a142b9e56d7d6daa1e595dacb00c9db/enum.c#L845), it does retain ordering:

```c
static VALUE
partition_i(RB_BLOCK_CALL_FUNC_ARGLIST(i, arys))
{
    struct MEMO *memo = MEMO_CAST(arys);
    VALUE ary;
    ENUM_WANT_SVALUE();

    if (RTEST(enum_yield(argc, i))) {
        ary = memo->v1;
    }
    else {
        ary = memo->v2;
    }
    rb_ary_push(ary, i);
    return Qnil;
}
```

*This code gets called from the [public interface](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/437392232a142b9e56d7d6daa1e595dacb00c9db/enum.c#L884).*

Essentially, the ordering in which your enumerable emits objects gets retained with the above logic.